# Custom ValidationTextBox in Dojo

Tags: validation, dojo

I am new to Dojo programming and trying to create a ValidationTextBox for username input. I would like to have three criteria: 1. users can only input alphanumeric characters and 2. minimum length of a username is 6 character 3. this field is required

So far my input looks like:

```
<input name="username" 
   type="text" 
   id="username" 
   class="reqd1" 
   required="true" 
   trim="true" 
   lowercase="true" 
   promptMessage="Username" 
   invalidMessage="Please only enter alphanumeric characters."
   maxlength="12" 
   regExp="[\w]+"
   intermediateChanges="false"
   dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" />
```

I have three questions: 
1. how I can check for the the minimum character of the username field?
2. Is there a way to change the invalidMessage programatically?
3. How I can check the length of the username field without using regEx?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. regExp="\w{6,12}"
2. dijit.byId("username").set("invalidMessage", "new message");
3. I think regExp is the best way in your case